# updating opengl version to use gephi

Tags: windows, opengl, gephi

When I open Gephi I get the following error message:

```
"Your OpenGl version (1.1.0) is too low to display the graph. Update your graphical drivers or configuration."
Current hardware:
Microsoft Coporation
GDI Generic
Version;1.1.0
```

I am running Windows 8, and my graphics card is an ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5000 Series (Microsoft Coporation -WDDM v1.20). Apparently, this graphics card has support for OpenGL 3.2 ([Driver info](http://www.amd.com/us/products/notebook/graphics/ati-mobility-hd-5700/pages/hd-5650-specs.aspx))! Trying to solve this, I googled and came across this: [link1](http://www.iblogworld.com/2013/02/solve-current-opengl-version-110-is-too.html#.Ud8_HG0SSHg). It isn't very helpful to me because after I disable the driver signed I don't know which driver to download!

1. How can I update my OpenGL version (or whatever is really causing the problem) so that Gephi works?

If you need any more information about my system, let me know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gephi reports your current hardware as "GDI Generic", not the radeon hd 5000, so I don't think you have the correct drivers.

Try using the drivers from amd and see if this will fix it.
http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx

Comment: I should have asked sooner... What does GDI stand for?

Comment: graphics device interface, it means windows has downloaded the generic drivers for your discrete graphics card. Installing the drivers which your card is meant to be used with should fix this problem.

Comment: Thank you so much! Staying up to date on software is so difficult on windows... Hopefully it works, I should know soon. Finally! It works! :) You literally made my day!

Comment: That's great to hear! Glad it's working now :)

Comment: So, I just switched to Ubuntu. Gephi doesn't have any problem starting but it will not draw a graph...